# Resolv.conf reset automatically after reboot to the wrong dns

Tags: domain-name-system, ubuntu-16.04, resolv.conf

With my ubuntu 16.04, my /etc/resolv.conf change every system start

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf  
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Network-manager have the correct dns name server 192.168.1.1
I removed bind9 and all related packages.
No special config on rc folders nor rc.local
No dns-nameserver options with `/etc/network/interfaces`.

I missed something? What app can change this file automatically?

Comment: Do you use DHCP?

Comment: Perhaps this could answer your question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserver-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away

Comment: Yes I use DHCP  
  
Thanks, the solution is to comment  
#dns=dnsmask  
from network-manager.conf

Answer (score 0):

Do you use DHCP?

- Does maybe your DHCP server send wrong nameserver pointers?
- Do you have a custom dhcp.conf that uses it's own nameserver config and
  ignores the DHCP server?

If you don't use DHCP:

- Did you read and understand https://askubuntu.com/questions/627899/nameserver-127-0-1-1-in-resolv-conf-wont-go-away ?
- Do you have a templating mechanism?

Comment: Thank you,  
I am using network-manager (iface wlan with dhcp)  
But when displaying dns with network-manager show interface informations: 
 
the correct ones are showing.

Answer (score 0):

I can't remember when this started, but resolv.conf is a system generated file.

Anything (more specifically, static options from previous resolv.conf's) that you want adding to that should be put in `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure resolvconf service is running, enable it:

```
sudo systemctl start resolvconf.service
```

then enter this one:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head
```

then add/change the nameservers you want and save, and then modify the resolv.conf and close.

remember to set your network-manager dns to what you've set in resolv.conf